# how can i add the sendgrid webhook event Json response in a firebase cloud firestore using node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I have no idea how to implement this thing but before that, I have done a part of SendGrid where any document is created then it will send the email to the user. but this part what I am asking I has no idea how to proceed.this is my first part of this implementation wherein any collection if a new record is created then it will send email to the particular email and there is a response called event Object I want to write a cloud function to store the data. and I don't know how to start this function or proceed with this problem.

```
"use strict";
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount1 = require("./key.json");

const newProject = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount1),
  databaseURL: "xyz"
});
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const sgMailKey = "key";
sgMail.setApiKey(sgMailKey);


 exports.sentMail = functions.firestore
  .document("/Offices/{officeId}")
  .onCreate((documentSnapshot,event) => {
    const documentData = documentSnapshot.data()
    const officeID = event.params.officeId;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
    const db = newProject.firestore();
    return db.collection("Offices").doc(officeID).get()
      .then(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const msg = {
          to: "amarjeetkumars34@gmail.com",
          from: "singhamarjeet045@gmail.com",
          text: "hello from this side",
          templateId: "d-8ecfa59aa9d2434eb8b7d47d58b4f2cf",
          substitutionWrappers: ["{{", "}}"],
          substitutions: {
            name: data.name
          }
        };
        return sgMail.send(msg);
      })
      .then(() => console.log("payment mail sent success"))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
```

and the expected output of my question be like a collection name XYZ wherein an object there are three fields like

```
{email:"xyz@gmail.com",
event:"processed",
timestamp:123555558855},
{email:"xyz@gmail.com",
event:"recieved",
timestamp:123555558855},
{email:"xyz@gmail.com",
event:"open",
timestamp:123555558855}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you will read in the [Sendgrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/):

> SendGrid's Event Webhook will notify a URL of your choice via HTTP
> POST with information about events that occur as SendGrid processes
> your email

To implement the HTTP endpoint in your Firebase Project, you will implement an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0) that will be called by the Sendgrid webhook through an HTTPS POST request.

Each call from the Sendgrid webhook will concern a specific [event](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/event/) and you will be able, in your Cloud Function, to get the value of the event (`processed`, `delivered`, etc...).

Now, you need in your Cloud Function to be able to link a specific event with a specific email that was previously sent through your Cloud Function. For that you should use [custom arguments](http://custom%20arguments).

More precisely, you would add to your `msg` object (that you pass to the `send()` method)  a unique identifier. A classical value is a Firestore document ID, like `event.params.officeId` but could be any other unique ID that you generate in you Cloud Function.

---

### Example of implementation

In your Cloud Function that sends the email, pass the `officeId` in a `custom_args` object, as shown below:

```
 exports.sentMail = functions.firestore
  .document("/Offices/{officeId}")
  .onCreate((documentSnapshot,event) => {

    const documentData = documentSnapshot.data();

    const officeId = event.params.officeId;

    const msg = {
          to: "amarjeetkumars34@gmail.com",
          from: "singhamarjeet045@gmail.com",
          text: "hello from this side",
          templateId: "d-8ecfa59aa9d2434eb8b7d47d58b4f2cf",
          substitutionWrappers: ["{{", "}}"],
          substitutions: {
            name: documentData.name
          },
          custom_args: {
             "officeId": officeId
          }
    };
    
    return sgMail.send(msg)
      .then(() => {
         console.log("payment mail sent success"));
         return null;
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err)
         return null;
      });
  });
```

Note that you get the data of the newly created document (the one which triggers the Cloud Function) through `documentSnapshot.data()`: you don't need to query for the same document in your Cloud Function.

---

Then, create a simple [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=1), as follows:

```
exports.sendgridWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const body = req.body; //body is an array of JavaScript objects

    const promises = [];

    body.forEach(elem => {

        const event = elem.event;
        const eventTimestamp = elem.timestamp;
        const officeId = elem.officeId;

        const updateObj = {};
        updateObj[event] = true;
        updateObj[event + 'Timestamp'] = eventTimestamp;

        promises.push(admin.firestore().collection('Offices').doc(officeId).update(updateObj));

    });

    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(200).end();
        })

})
```

Deploy it and grab its URL as shown in the terminal: it should be like `https://us-central1-<your-project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/sendgridWebhook`.

Note that here I use `admin.firestore().collection('Offices')...`. You may use `const db = newProject.firestore(); ... db.collection('Offices')...`

Also note that the body of the HTTPS POST request sent by the Sendgrid webhook contains an array of JavaScript objects, therefore we will use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to treat these different objects, i.e. write to the Firestore document with `officeId` the different events.

Then you need to set-up the Webhook in the Sendgrid platform, in the "Mail Settings/Event Notification" section, as explained in the [doc](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/) and as shown below.

[image]

Comment: app.post('/mailevent', async(req,res)=> {
  try {
    const {email,timestamp,event} = req.body;
    const data = {
      email,
      timestamp,
      event
    }
    const maileventRef = await db.collection('mailevents').add(data);
    const mailevent = await maileventRef.get();
    res.json({
      id:maileventRef.id,
      data:office.data()
    })

 }catch(err){res.status(500).send(err)  }}) can you tell me this is the way you are telling me to implement and when i deploy this they give me a ur which i have to paste it and generate the JSON and store it into the collection ?

Comment: @PremjeetKumar Give me 1 hour approx, as I am commuting, but I'll give you an answer!

Comment: @PremjeetKumar sorry today I’ll not be able to work out an answer but you can count on me tomorrow!

Comment: please if possible Thank you

Comment: if you are free can you please suggest me anything regarding my question

Comment: @PremjeetKumar See the answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207889/discussion-between-premjeet-kumar-and-renaud-tarnec).